# Adding fade to jQuery image swap

Tags: jquery, image, fadein, fade

I'm building an app to display different colours of a car when the colour swatch is clicked. I've built the jQuery to nicely swap out the image based on the swatch that is clicked.

However, I'm struggling to make the new image fade in nicely over the one that is already visible.

```
$('a.swatchItem').click(function() { // on click of swatch
    var carID = $(this).attr('id'); // grab the clicked ID
    $('a.swatchItem').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class
    $(this).addClass('active'); // Add active class to current swatch
    $("#carItem").attr('src',"img/models/longtitude/" + carID + ".png"); // replace with new car image
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$('a.swatchItem').click(function() { // on click of swatch
  var carID = $(this).attr('id'); // grab the clicked ID
  $('a.swatchItem').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class
  $(this).addClass('active'); // Add active class to current swatch
  $("#carItem").fadeOut('fast', function(){
      $(this).attr("src", "img/models/longtitude/" + carID + ".png").fadeIn();
  }); // replace with new car image
  return false;
});
```

#### [A simple fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/e5st4/)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct because you have answered my question. The (very slight) issue is that its fades out then in (so you can see the background briefly). What I meant, but didn't explain properly, is I wanted the new image to fade over the top so it's a smooth transition without seeing any of the background. I might use your example and work some z-index's in somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

Break it into steps:

1. Fade the image out
2. Wait for fade to complete
3. Change the `src`
4. Wait for image to load
5. Fade it in

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/EqEma/***

You could do steps 1 thru 3 using the same handler as you are using:

```
$('a.swatchItem').click(function() { 
    // fade the image out
    $("#carItem").fadeOut(function() {
        // on completion change the src
        $("#carItem").attr('src', "...");     
    });
    return false;
});
```

For the steps 4 and 5, add an handler to the image itself:

```
$("#carItem").load(function() {
    // once the image is loaded, fade it back in
    $(this).fadeIn()
});
```

**Edit:**

You may not wait for the fadeout to complete in fact. May skip step 2. The image can load along with fadeout animation.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/EqEma/1/***

```
$('a.swatchItem').click(function() { 
    $("#carItem").fadeOut();
    $("#carItem").attr('src', "...");   
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This does work - But I'm still getting and fadeout once the new image has loaded in (might be a Chrome Mac issue).